# cordova-plugin-crypto-file returns connection error when app luanched

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add cordova-plugin-crypto-file 1.4.0 to my ionic project with android 10
I have followed [the guide](https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-plugin-crypto-file)  by changing WebResourceResponse in `platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/ionicframework/cordova/webview/IonicWebViewEngine.java` file and adding the tag of the port in the `confix.xml` file also but i got error

> "err_connection_refused https://localhost/index.html"